# Automounted USB devices are read only

Tags: usb, mount, permissions

Since I upgraded to Ubuntu 12.10 the automout of USB devices does not work as expected. When I plug in a storage device it is recognized correctly but I do not have write privileges on it. I thought, that maybe the permissions of /media are not correctly set, but I don't know, how they have to be. They are like this:

```
drwxr-xr-x  14 root  root   4096 Jan 13 19:37 media
```

I also checked whether my user is a member of the group  *plugdev* and he definitely is.

What else could be the cause of that problem?

Update: Here is the dmesg output after plugging in an USB storage device:  http://pastebin.com/pJ7qebQR

Comment: Could you paste/link the relevant part of `dmesg` output from when you plug in or mount the drive?

Comment: How do I do this?

Comment: Open a terminal and type `dmesg` right after plugging in the drive, and a few of the last lines should have information on the device detection. Or you can copy/paste the whole output (censor if needed) on [Pastebin](http://www.pastebin.com) and share the link here.

Comment: Added the output to the post above.

Comment: Could you paste/
link the output of
`cat /etc/fstab`   
and   
`mount`   
(pls ignore the above commend as i can't edit or delete from my phone)

Comment: How many usb devices you tried ??   
    [21373.939990]  sdf: unknown partition table.  
May be it's your usb hardware problem. Try to create a new partition table.

Comment: I think you (and I) are suffering from this bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/1021375

Answer (score 36):

I think you are suffering the bug [#1021375](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/1021375)

You can workaround it by renaming the folder ~/.config/nautilus and then logout and log back in.

1. `mv ~/.config/nautilus ~/.config/nautilus-bak`
2. Logout.
3. Login.

Comment: I don't know if there are multiple possible causes of this problem, but I don't know why this answer hasn't gotten more upvotes. This was exactly my problem, with the exception of the fact that I was using the nemo file manager rather than nautilus. But I confirmed that I could create/edit/delete files using an alternative file manager (PCManFM), the terminal, and the application Save File dialog of gedit and LibreOffice, so the problem only affects nautilus/nemo. Your proposed workaround also seems to have done the trick.

Comment: This answer is what solved my problem. Thanks !

Comment: killall nautilus is enough, no need for logging out. :)

Comment: didn't work for me; I had to deinstall usbmount, unmount with disc-utilities and mount again. then it worked. before that, renaming ~/.config/nautilus didn't help

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 16.04 and the problem appeared out of thin air. The solution still solves the problem.

Comment: `killall nautilus` did the trick as @isset suggested. Thanks.

Answer (score 21):

```
sudo mount -o remount,rw /media/MonterFolderName
```

This shall solve the issue. I am not sure how to make it permanent. I am not sure if `chmod` would work if in case the USB is not mounted in readwrite mode in the first place.

Tested on  Ubuntu 12.10 and 13.

Comment: may I suggest `sudo mount -o remount,rw /media/$USER/*`

Comment: did not work in ubuntu 16.04 :(

Comment: Sorry, It was in older versions of android, I had tested it on ubuntu 13 max I think.

Comment: Ubuntu I meant...

Comment: `mount: cannot remount /dev/sda1 read-write, is write-protected`

Comment: Which version of ubuntu are you on?

Comment: Didn't work for me in 16.04 LTS

Answer (score 11):

When the USB is inserted it's mounted on `/media/<username>` that you should have permissions through an access control list.

You can check what the permissions are e.g.

```
bcbc@23:34:50:~$ getfacl /media/bcbc
# file: media/bcbc
# owner: root
# group: root
user::rwx
user:bcbc:r-x
group::---
mask::r-x
other::---
```

If there is no access control list, just delete the directory and it will recreate it with the correct permissions.

```
sudo rmdir /media/<username>
```

Or add the ACL:

```
sudo setfacl -m u:<username>:rx /media/<username>
```

Comment: THIS - this is the solution that finally works for me.  On Mint, Kubuntu, Debian and Ubuntu.  Nautilus was never the real issue at all (and was not even used in a couple of the distros listed).  Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

## Problem appears to have gone away

This is a 5 y/o question on short term release Ubuntu 12.10. The `dmesg` link is no longer available in the OP's question. But if I plug in a Ubuntu 18.04 Live USB with persistent storage `dmesg` reveals:

```
$ dmesg | tail -n18
[115528.249547] usb-storage 1-9:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[115528.250152] scsi host2: usb-storage 1-9:1.0
[115528.250474] usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
[115528.255685] usbcore: registered new interface driver uas
[115529.281407] scsi 2:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Verbatim STORE N GO       PMAP PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[115529.282090] sd 2:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 0
[115529.992200] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] 30261248 512-byte logical blocks: (15.5 GB/14.4 GiB)
[115529.992998] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[115529.993006] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 23 00 00 00
[115529.993787] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] No Caching mode page found
[115529.993797] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[115530.592616]  sdb: sdb1 sdb2 sdb3 sdb4 sdb5
[115530.596279] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
[115531.018019] EXT4-fs (sdb5): warning: mounting unchecked fs, running e2fsck is recommended
[115531.470201] EXT4-fs (sdb5): mounted filesystem without journal. Opts: (null)
[115531.480738] ISO 9660 Extensions: Microsoft Joliet Level 3
[115531.483397] ISO 9660 Extensions: Microsoft Joliet Level 3
[115531.512219] ISO 9660 Extensions: RRIP_1991A
```

Unlike OP implies, there is no warning for read-only. Notice the line:

> **sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off**

Apparently whatever the problem was 5 years ago, it no longer exists today under **Ubuntu 16.04 LTS**. Also for the only other LTS version today, **14.04** I can't remember this being a problem either. Only SD RAM cards come to mind as being read only, which is a different problem altogether.

Comment: I ran into this yesterday on 16.04 so I have to disagree with you that the issue is "gone"

Comment: I should say with a default install. There are all kinds of security overrides that employers want to install. For example to prevent employees downloading a list of customer data to USB.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing is wrong with the mounting options and fstab file, as far as my knowledge, you just have to use below command to get the Required right permissions on the media folder. and I will explain you why.

1) your current permissions on the folder as you mentioned are as below. (Apologize if you know this and I'm bothering you with it.)

`drwxr-xr-x  14 root  root   4096 Jan 13 19:37 media` in this d stands for directory, first group of rwx stands for the rights of the user who owns that object, which is in your case root.

second group of rwx stands for the rights of the group who owns that object & here you have only r-x which means even if you are in the sudoers file or in the admin group you do not have rights to write in it.

Third group of rwx is or other users, who are not owner of that object nor in the group who has ownership rights of that object. if your case it is again r-x only. so that is why you do not have write permissions on it.

2) So you need to change permissions of the media folder. (I am going to consider that you are in admin group or sudoers file, because this will work only in that case). so this is what you need to do.

```
$ sudo chmod -R 775 /media
```

3) This will give you required write permissions on the all auto mounted drives.

Please check and let me know if this does not work will tell you what else can be done to fix this issue.

Comment: One more thing... About ACL does not come automatically installed with OS ... so unless you have installed it.. it stays out of Question in your case. if you have installed it pleas let me know.

Comment: No it won't give you write permission, and it's a bad idea too. Being in the sudo group or admin group (if there is one) does not give you group permissions where the group owner is root, so this will not change anything for you. Please also consider the difference between file and directory permissions and possible adverse consequences when recommending the use of the `-R` flag to `chmod`. For one thing, the permissions of `/media/$USER` should (now) be 750 with an ACL for `$USER`. (Ubuntu versions later than 15.04 must have the `acl` package since `systemd` depends on it.)

Comment: I had that problem today and i solved it just doing chmod over the mountpoint. I am able to write to subfolders, is just the drive root the one complaining. So, `chmod 775 /media/user/device` is good enough.

Answer (score 1):

I hit this problem too, in my case it was a fat32 corruption problem allowing to read it but not to write.

Then if your usb key is a fat32, it might be that your filesyste is corrupted.

To verify do a **sudo dmesg**

```
[17183.485565] FAT-fs (sdc1): error, corrupted directory (invalid entries)
[17205.406905] FAT-fs (sdc1): Volume was not properly unmounted. Some data may be corrupt. Please run fsck.
```

then unmout it, **sudo fsck.vfat *your_device_partition*** it then mount it again.

in my specific case :

```
sudo fsck.vfat /dev/sdc1
fsck.fat 4.1 (2017-01-24)
0x41: Dirty bit is set. Fs was not properly unmounted and some data may be     corrupt.
1) Remove dirty bit
2) No action
? 1
/T90bis
 Start does point to root directory. Deleting dir. 
Reclaimed 93 unused clusters (1523712 bytes).
Free cluster summary wrong (1248506 vs. really 1248599)
1) Correct
2) Don't correct
? 1
Perform changes ? (y/n) y
/dev/sdc1: 916 files, 704527/1953126 clusters
```